# Can't run Rails test or make migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, model-view-controller, tdd

Hello I am following Michael Hart's Ruby on Rails tutorial, I am trying to run test but when I use the  `rails test` command I get this response code:

```
migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: 
rails db:migrate  RAILS_ENV=test
```

Can someone explain why I am running this command in the first place?
Unfortunately running this command does not resolve the issue either, after running it I get the following output:

```
random numbers.... CreateUsers: migrating
--create_table(:users)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occured this and all later migrations cancelled;

SQLLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exist
```

I'm not sure why this error is occurring either. Any method to resolve these issues would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You are prompted to run the command because a previous command errored out and left your environment in a bad state.  The output indicates the `users` table already exists in the database. Suggest you drop the database, recreate it and rerun migrations.

Comment: To add on to @dbugger, you can drop the tables and then attempt to recreate them. After the tables are all created successfully you can run the [migrations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_migrations.html). Try `rails db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a difference between your schema.rb file and the actual state of your database, and because of that Rails are trying to execute migrations that have already been executed.

The reason why this happened are numerous. It may be a result of a previous command that dit not execute properly or you may have manually edited your schema.rb file, for example.

The easiest way to solve this in development/test environment is by dropping and re-creating your entire database. You can achieve that running the following command:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails db:setup
```

Which will have the same effect as running the following commands in sequence:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails db:drop
RAILS_ENV=test rails db:create
RAILS_ENV=test rails db:migrate
```

As for your question: "Why I am running this command in the first place?", well, you want your database to be up to date when running your tests.

Rails has separate databases for development and test environment, and when you run rails db:migrate passing RAILS_ENV=test you are applying all the changes changes described on your pending migrations to your test database.